# How can I get the URL phrase from $routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs

for example here is the code:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/devices-list', {
        templateUrl: 'Views/Layouts/devices-list.html',
        controller: 'deviceLibraryController'
    });
```

but I want to have a shortcut doing so.

```
    $routeProvider.when('/devices-list', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/Layouts' + this.path +'.html', // where this.path would be '/device-list'
            controller: 'deviceLibraryController'
    });
```

is there any similar step doing so?

Update:

I found there is one way doing similar situation with `$routeProvider.when('/:name', {...})`, but it parse all `:name` in variable way. What I need is the path is already specified and return the templateURL by retrieving the the path from $routeProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [the reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when),

> templateUrl – {(string|Function)=} – path or function that returns a
>   path to an html template that should be used by ngView.
>
> If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following
>   parameters:
>
> {`Array.<Object>`} - route parameters extracted from the current
>   $location.path() by applying the current route

Though it appears that there is a typo, it is clear that [route parameters param is an object](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/test/ngRoute/routeSpec.js#L1280-L1289), not an array of objects.

So it may be

```
$routeProvider.when('/devices-list/:phrase', {
    templateUrl: (params) => 'Views/Layouts' + params.phrase +'.html',
    ...
});
```